# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\sourceit\envel.php on line 12

Tags: php

Есть файл с числами,надо посчитать .Результат выводится в строку,но надо чтоб после 10 числа,переходило на новую строку и так всю строку разбивало на 10 чисел на одной строке..

```
$fh = fopen($argv[1], 'r');
while (false !== ($line = fgets($fh))) {
    list($stud,$proc) = explode('|', trim($line));

    $proc = explode(' ',trim($proc));

    $count = '';
    foreach ($proc as $pr){
        $count = ceil($stud * $pr/100);

        foreach( $count as &$sr) {
            if ( mb_strlen($sr , $enc) > 10 ) {
                $sr = mb_substr($sr,0,10,$enc)."\n";
            }
        }

        echo $sr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то мне не понятно как ты пытаешься $count , которое является числом перебирать циклом? Какая задача, по точнее. Что ты должен делать с $count?

Comment: ну у меня получается строка $count с числами ,я хочу чтоб после каждого 10 числа переходило на новую строку...

Comment: Может запихнуть его в массив?а потом с помощью цикла перебирать и после 10 числа переходить на новую?

Comment: Ну ну ну... $count у тебя не число, ceil — Округляет дробь в большую сторону. Тут оно к тебя не может быть никак массивом/строкой.

Comment: Формат файла ещё скинь.

Comment: посмотри ниже написал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen('file', 'r');
$arr = array();
while (false !== ($line = fgets($fh))) {
    list($stud,$proc) = explode('|', trim($line));

    $proc = explode(' ',trim($proc));
    $count = '';
    $summ = 0;
    foreach ($proc as $pr){
        $summ += $pr;
        $arr[] = ceil($stud * $pr/100);
    }
}

$g = 0;
$itemsInRow = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
   $g++;
   if ($g <= $itemsInRow) {
        echo $arr[$i] . ' ';
        if ($g == $itemsInRow) {
            echo '<br />';
            $g = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

62|3,2258 6,4516 17,7419 19,3548 24,1935 16,129 8,0645 4,8387 0 0
16|0 12,5 25 31,25 18,75 0 6,25 6,25 0 0
18|0 22,2222 27,7778 27,7778 16,6667 5,5556 0 0 0 0
69|7,2464 10,1449 23,1884 24,6377 17,3913 11,5942 2,8986 2,8986 0 0
198|8,0808 9,0909 24,7475 19,1919 15,6566 13,6364 6,5657 2,5253 0,5051 0
29|3,4483 6,8966 20,6897 10,3448 20,6897 13,7931 13,7931 3,4483 6,8966 0
3|0 0 33,3333 0 66,6667 0 0 0 0 0
188|9,0426 7,9787 22,3404 21,2766 12,766 13,8298 5,3191 4,7872 2,6596 0
2|0 0 50 50 0 0 0 0 0 0
55|3,6364 9,0909 25,4545 21,8182 7,2727 18,1818 7,2727 1,8182 5,4545 0
12|0 33,3333 8,3333 16,6667 25 8,3333 8,3333 0 0 0
4|0 0 25 0 50 25 0 0 0 0
2|0 50 0 0 50 0 0 0 0 0

обычный txt формат

Comment: так я почти дописал, что надо сделать с числами после |

Comment: где ? я не вижу

Comment: ну у тебя идет до | это студент `$stud`, а после идут числа, что надо сделать со $stud и числами. Просуммировать или что?

Comment: чтоб число $stud умножить на каждое число и поделить на 100,и вывести по 10 чисел в каждой строке

Comment: первая строка 11 получается,а последняя 9

Comment: все подкорректировал, не туда вписал $g++;